# What are the consequences of just eating sandwiches for breakfast and lunch?

Tags: nutrition, muscle-gain, carbohydrate, nutrition-information

I've wondered a long time if eating cereals with chocalate, honey and sandwiches with sandwich filling like jam, peanut butter, chocalate, syrup, cheese, salami etc. would be bad or good or maybe just neutral.

> So what are the consequences (both positive and negative) of just eating sandwiches for breakfast and lunch almost all the time?

**Note:**
I'm a student and it's very hard for me to study and work at the same time to pay for the food. I recently hired a personal trainer and made him draft a diet. I soon realized it would cost me around €250,00 (appr. $289.5) per month which is something I can't keep up with.

> *Bonus question* : So what tips do you have for me to get the nutrients I need?

**EDIT:**

I follow a power (strength) training as it is called in my language. [Monday and Friday] Chest: Benchpress (close and wide grip both 4 sets of 10 reps), Dumbbell Flyes (15 reps), Superset that consists of Cable crossover (slightly below shoulder line), Push-ups and then Low cable front raises (all 15 reps). They are performed directly after eachoter. Then Prone 45° Incline reverse-grip Barbell front raises (12 reps) last but not least Prone 45° barbell spider curls (8 reps). (Tuesday and Saturday) Back: Seatle Cable row (5 sets of 10 reps), Bent Over Barbell Row ( 6 sets of 14, 10, 7, 7, 10, 14 reps (20, 25 and 30 kg) ),Assisted Pull-up, Lat Pull down, Superset (Dumbell Row and Cable one arm lateral raise), Triceps revers grip pushdown,  Lying barbell Triceps Extension. 
(Wednesday) Leg day: Leg extension Machine, Single leg press, Barbell Squat, leg press, seated leg curl, lying hamstring curl. 
Abbs I try to do as much as I can .

P.S.:

- I do however take protein shakes (True Mass BSN; 35 grams before the training and 40 grams after within a 30 minute-time interval). But I'm planning to stop doing that.
- My sandwiche is just one slice of bread fold in half. It's not like [this](https://www.google.be/search?q=sandwich&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRt7PVidPcAhVODewKHbunBe0Q_AUICigB&biw=1536&bih=728#imgrc=fRr2Y2MMrNpFrM:) but more like [this](https://www.google.be/search?biw=1536&bih=728&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=EHFlW7veKsfGkwXuorjwDg&q=slice+of+bread+fold+in+half&oq=slice+of+bread+fold+in+half&gs_l=img.3...2690.4887.0.5042.13.13.0.0.0.0.151.955.12j1.13.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.2.224...0i19k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i24k1.0.60AtUEKbO8A#imgrc=iAqtgqSMmt8a2M:). One slice of bread weighs 34 grams. I often eat the brown ones.

Comment: Consequence #1: you’re going to get really sick of sandwiches!

Comment: Consequence #2: You're missing out on variety in your diet. If you're eating mostly the same stuff, how do you expect to get ALL the micronutrients, vitamins and minerals that your body needs?

Comment: That's in my dinner. I eat plentry of fish, chicken and sort of that when it's evening.

Comment: @G__: I have eaten them since I was 3 years old. So it's not gonna be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Jam, chocolate (candy), syrup, and sugar cereal (most) in significant daily quantities may ultimately increase your insulin resistance and thus risk of diabetes and other health conditions along with fat gain and greater difficulty losing it.

Salami, Cheese, and Peanut-butter (most have lower sugar with beneficial nutrients) are the healthier choices here - limiting bread or at-least going with the highest nutritious wheat bread with high fiber (unless you are gluten-intolerant) will allow for healthier sandwiches.  Adding veggies such as lettuce, spinach, and large frozen bag to combine with various meals with provided additional nutrients on a budget.  More meats (preferably grass fed or at-least least processed) such as fish, chicken, or steak can definitely help with muscle gain and higher energy throughout the day - less hunger. Better snacks include: various nuts, and organic butter can all provider greater nutrition with empirical fitness results in long-term studies. Limiting fruits is ok and safe, a small percentage of the daily intake is fine, or even around once a week.

Ultimately avoid the processed carb and sugar ridden foods and drinks the most which are unfortunately the most advertised. Also read and experiment with intermittent fasting (i.e. only eating within a relatively 8 hour window each day, allowing the other 16 hours to be fasted) if you don't have any serious medical conditions that require you to eat a large amount of calories throughout the day, the benefits are quite astounding and you will notice many mental and physical benefits after just a week including greater focus, less bloating, better sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and no I'm not gluten-intolerant, and I don't have any serious medical conditions. I have fasted ramadan and it was amazing regarding my fat loss (from 17% till 14%) just not eating for 18 hours straight and then eat moderately. Besides I don't use large quantities of jam, chocolate and syrup on my sandwiches. I wasn't talking about chocolate candy but chocolate on my sandwiches.

Comment: It would mean a lot if you have some sources that prove your claims/ conclusions.